# Give a string as a input and print the next alphabet. Input: xyzabc Output: yzabcd

Tags: python

```
user_input = (input("Enter: ")).lower()
for item in user_input:
    output = chr(ord(item)+1)
    print(output, end="")
```

#I have tried this but while I run the program the after z it is printing {. But I need to print a after z. How can it be done?

Comment: You could check if the current character is equal to `z`. Do you know how to write an if statement?

Comment: read the docs to see what `ord` and `chr` does, and what ASCII values are. Then think of a login (which may include `if` like @khelwood suggested).

Answer (score 3):

Use modulo arithmetic. In place of

```
chr(ord(item)+1)
```

you can use:

```
chr(ord("a") + (ord(item) - ord("a") + 1) % 26)
```

(For efficiency, you could store the `ord("a")` in a variable rather than evaluate it every time.)